# A .po Generator written in PHP

Tags: php, translation, gettext, po, mo

Is there such a thing out there?

A script that's able to create a .po file from .php files dropped inside a directory/

Comment: You mean like extracting `gettext` calls?

Comment: yes :D strings from functions like __() etc.

Comment: What about expressions? Like `_('hello'.$world);`?

Comment: i dont think they are valid..

Comment: They are valid, but if you don't use them, I may have a solution for you.

Comment: What's wrong with invoking `xgettext`?

Comment: Does it have to be scripted or could you use PoEdit? [link](http://www.poedit.net/) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no PHP i18n resource extractor as far as I know.

You just install gettext tools and invoke xgettext command from PHP with exec(). Although the tool written in C is not what you originally asked, the tool is well used by a lot of people so it would be far better quality-wise than writing something new in PHP with regex or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tool to create the .po files from PHP files
http://www.icanlocalize.com/tools/php_scanner